# How do I group 90th percentiles by two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a large dataframe 7191 obs. of 19 variables. The columns are Month, Day, Year, and Site1 through Site16. Where Month is either June, July, August, September, or October.

Here is the beginning of my data, which I believe has only numerals in the columns site1-site16. Currently, I'm double checking to make sure.

```
dput(head(No_PS_for_Calculations ))
structure(list(Month = c("June", "June", "June", "June", "June", 
"June"), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Year = c(1970, 1970, 1970, 
1970, 1970, 1970), Site1 = c("11.531", "12.298", "12.732", "12.619", 
"12.5", "13.201"), Site2 = c("11.185", "11.439", "12.17", "12.432", 
"12.337", "12.492"), Site3 = c("11.147", "11.496", "11.645", 
"12.208", "12.644", "12.971"), Site4 = c("11.393", "11.707", 
"11.961", "12.135", "12.809", "13.041"), Site5 = c("11.797", 
"11.925", "12.34", "12.525", "13.01", "13.548"), Site6 = c("11.853", 
"11.974", "12.16", "12.481", "12.459", "12.838"), Site7 = c("12.319", 
"12.46", "12.476", "12.729", "13.026", "13.032"), Site8 = c("12.557", 
"12.643", "12.789", "12.975", "13.202", "13.339"), Site9 = c("12.774", 
"13.337", "13.896", "13.897", "13.819", "14.054"), Site10 = c("12.819", 
"13.202", "13.783", "14.298", "14.284", "14.309"), Site11 = c("13.151", 
"13.556", "13.833", "14.08", "14.244", "14.841"), Site12 = c("13.61", 
"13.57", "14.111", "14.073", "14.331", "14.849"), Site13 = c("13.802", 
"13.872", "14.244", "14.249", "14.255", "14.818"), Site14 = c("14.138", 
"14.275", "14.332", "14.522", "14.244", "14.927"), Site15 = c("14.138", 
"14.616", "14.766", "14.697", "14.61", "14.694"), Site16 = c("14.208", 
"14.627", "14.928", "14.829", "14.69", "14.762")), row.names = 151:156, class = "data.frame")
```

For my analysis I am interested in finding the 90th percentile for each month in each year. For example for 1970, I need the 90th percentile for June, July, August, September, and October. I've tried a few different ways but keep getting stuck in the same spot so I thought I'd ask for help.

```
result <- No_PS_for_Calculations %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(across(Site1:`Site16`, quantile, probs = .9, .names = 'percent90_{col}'))
data.frame(result)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across(Site1:Site16, quantile, probs = 0.9, .names = "percent90_{col}")`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i The error occurred in group 1: Year = 1970, Month = "August".
```

I've been able to find the percentile grouped by month but now need to include year for further analysis.

What is the best way to get the 90th Percentiles presented by year and then month?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: (Formatting code in Stack sites uses code-fences, which you tried to use, but ... the code fences `\`\`\`` must be on lines by themselves, not shared with any code. The only exception is if there is a language hint on the first fence, such as `\`\`\`lang-r`. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more details.)

Comment: One of your columns is likely `character`, check `str(No_PS_for_Calculations)` to see which are your culprits. Note that `Site1:Site16` here will choose any columns in between the two regardless of naming convention, so this is not just selecting `Site*` columns (in case that was a thought). You might be able to do `No_PS_for_Calculations %>% select(Year, Month, starts_with("Site")) %>% group_by(Year, Month) %>% summarise(...)`, removing any unintended columns.

Comment: I don't know what else we can do to help, though, without representative data. Can you please paste the output from `dput(head(No_PS_for_Calculations ))` into a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)?

Comment: I added the outcome from the dput(head(No_PS_for_Calculations )) to the question. As far as I can tell all the site columns should be numeric because they were all derived the same way, through an external model.

Comment: When you posted that, did you move that ***none*** of your `Site` columns are numeric and are instead all string? It seems likely that there are non-numbers somewhere in the full data, not here, so you need to verify your dara source to fix that problem. Once you've done that, reload the data and ensure it is being loaded as numbers. You can certainly use `as.numeric` to fix the columns in-place, though I suspect you may get warning from one or more rows (and this is fixing the symptom, not the problem).

Comment: It might be interesting to see the output from something like `No_PS_for_Calculations[!grepl("^[-+]?.*[^0-9.]", No_PS_for_Calculations$Site1),]` to look for non-numbers in one of the columns (it seems likely to show problems in the others too).

Comment: The original data only has numbers in the columns and no header/column titles. To add column headers, I added a row with the names, made that row be the header, and removed it from the data. Could that be changing the original data numerals to be read as something different? I'm happy to share my data, I just wasn't sure how to do it

Comment: Yes. Not sure how you did that, but you corrupted your own data.

Comment: If the file has no headers, then the preferred method is to read it in (`read.csv` or `read.table` or such, with `header=FALSE`), and then assign column names with `colnames(dat) <- c("col1", "col2", ...)`. If you used `rbind` or the like, you corrupt your data, almost guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem, I apparently complicated the column naming process by creating a column names item, then adding it as the first row and converting it to the column names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems likely that you have something non-numeric in a column between `Site1` and `Site16`. Some fake data:

```r
set.seed(42)
No_PS_for_Calculations <- data.frame(Year = rep(2020:2021, each = 3), Month = rep(c("Aug","Sep","Oct"), times = 2), Site1 = runif(6), Quux = sprintf("%0.03f", runif(6)), Site16 = runif(6))
No_PS_for_Calculations
#   Year Month     Site1  Quux    Site16
# 1 2020   Aug 0.9148060 0.737 0.9346722
# 2 2020   Sep 0.9370754 0.135 0.2554288
# 3 2020   Oct 0.2861395 0.657 0.4622928
# 4 2021   Aug 0.8304476 0.705 0.9400145
# 5 2021   Sep 0.6417455 0.458 0.9782264
# 6 2021   Oct 0.5190959 0.719 0.1174874

No_PS_for_Calculations %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(across(Site1:`Site16`, quantile, probs = .9, .names = 'percent90_{col}'))
+ > Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.
# x non-numeric argument to binary operator
# i Input `..1` is `(function (.cols = everything(), .fns = NULL, ..., .names = NULL) ...`.
# i The error occurred in group 1: Year = 2020, Month = "Aug".
```

If the non-numeric data (`"Quux"` column here) is not meant to be summarized, then you can select the columns you need to avoid any confusion:

```r
No_PS_for_Calculations %>% 
  select(Year, Month, starts_with("Site")) %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(across(Site1:`Site16`, quantile, probs = .9, .names = 'percent90_{col}'))
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# # Groups:   Year [2]
#    Year Month percent90_Site1 percent90_Site16
#   <int> <chr>           <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1  2020 Aug             0.915            0.737
# 2  2020 Oct             0.286            0.657
# 3  2020 Sep             0.937            0.135
# 4  2021 Aug             0.830            0.705
# 5  2021 Oct             0.519            0.719
# 6  2021 Sep             0.642            0.458
```

Another cause might be if a legitimate `Site` column is non-numeric, in which case you need to determine if you can easily convert to numeric. For instance, if `"Quux"` here is instead named `"Site2"`

```r
names(No_PS_for_Calculations)[4] <- "Site2"
```

then we can try to convert it inline:

```r
No_PS_for_Calculations %>%
  mutate(Site2 = as.numeric(Site2)) %>%
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%
  summarise(across(Site1:`Site16`, quantile, probs = .9, .names = 'percent90_{col}'))
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
# # Groups:   Year [2]
#    Year Month percent90_Site1 percent90_Site2 percent90_Site16
#   <int> <chr>           <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1  2020 Aug             0.915           0.737            0.935
# 2  2020 Oct             0.286           0.657            0.462
# 3  2020 Sep             0.937           0.135            0.255
# 4  2021 Aug             0.830           0.705            0.940
# 5  2021 Oct             0.519           0.719            0.117
# 6  2021 Sep             0.642           0.458            0.978
```

Of course, if there are non-number characters in there, you will get `NA`s, which is easily fixed given filters, cleaners, or similar.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if something that is numeric is being read as non-numeric?